# merge file using ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, merge, diff

I want to merge two files (git-wise merge) in the following way:

file1:

```
AAAA  
BBBB  
CCCC  

server1  
server2  

DDDD  
EEEE
```

file2:

```
AAAA  
BBBB  
CCCC  

server3  
server4  

DDDD  
EEEE
```

And I want the merged file, file3, to be:

```
AAAA  
BBBB  
CCCC  

server1  
server2  
server3  
server4  

DDDD  
EEEE
```

Is there a way to do it in ruby or with linux?

Comment: git has changesets. You need to have versioning, to know what was the previous files to be able to compare only the changesets. If the files have no previous versions, then merging them is a difficult task, as both files have a single changeset each, containing all the content of the file.

Comment: i need to change and edit a config file dynamically, and i am using templates. i have the old file in the server, and i create a new file with the new servers (server3, server4), and i need to merge the configuration files.

Comment: Do you really want to maintain those _blank_ lines in the merged file ?

Comment: Nop, its not a must.

Comment: So you'd like lines beginning with `server` sorted and merged whereas other lines will be just merged in whatever order they might be? I'm having a little trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve with this.